# How to add millisecond to date type using R?

Tags: r, datetime, unix-timestamp, milliseconds

I have a data frame status as following:

```
   sg           date_time      tick_count
1      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02          0
2      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02          6
3      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02         19
4      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02         11
5      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02         15
6      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02         17
7      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02         29
8      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02         24
9      4 2014-07-24 11:02:02         38
10     < 2014-07-24 11:02:02         30
11     < 2014-07-24 11:02:02         34
12     < 2014-07-24 11:02:02         40
13     < 2014-07-24 11:02:02         41
14     < 2014-07-24 11:02:02         42
15     < 2014-07-24 11:02:02         47
```

The unit of column tick_count is 100 millisecond. I need to add tick_count time on date_time to make a new time column.

I converted date_time to unix timestamp and then plus tick_count/10:

```
newtime <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(status$date_time, tz="Finland/Helsinki")+status$tick_count/10)
```

But the result is exact to second:

```
head(newtime)
[1] 1406188922 1406188923 1406188924 1406188923 1406188924 1406188924
```

What should I do to show the time with milliseconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is "just" a display issue.  Use

```
options("digits.secs"=6)
```

to see full precision.

Full example:

```
R> options("digits.secs"=0)    # reset
R> tt <- ISOdatetime(2014,7,28,10,11,12)
R> tt
[1] "2014-07-28 10:11:12 CDT"
R> tt <- tt + 1e-5
R> tt
[1] "2014-07-28 10:11:12 CDT"
R> options("digits.secs"=6)    # full precision
R> tt
[1] "2014-07-28 10:11:12.00001 CDT"
R>
```